# Php Str_replace for \&#39 doesnt work

Tags: php, str-replace, quotes, backslash

i have a title field for mysql field as this

```
Newyork\&#39; s best place
```

it seems

```
Newyork\ s best place
```

i want to change it as

```
Mewyork's best place
```

i make this but it doesn't work

```
str_replace("\&#39;", "'", $title);
```

Any suggestions?

Look this site title: http://www.kusadasisehirrehberi.com/

Orijinal codes

functions.php

```
      default:
  $baslik=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT title from ayar where id=1 limit 0,1"));
  $title=title_temizle($baslik['0']);
  $title=str_replace("\&#39;", "'", $title);
  }

  return $title;

  }
```

header.php

```
<title><?php echo $title ?> </title>
```

Comment: So whats the result?

Comment: Please provide more code! where you use it.

Comment: Also what do you get if you echo title before and after the str_replace?

Comment: @Chilion no it doesnt work

Comment: Do you have those darned magic_quotes enabled in your php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape backslash - \ too, because in your case you are escaping ampersand symbol - &

```
str_replace("\\&#39;", "'", $title);
```

Comment: Besides that, str_replace is not the way to go with entities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use html_entity_decode...

So:

```
 <?php
       echo html_entity_decode($field);
 ?>
```

In this example I assume that the string

> Newyork\' s best place

Is in $field.

Also see: http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities

========

Updated:

Try the following, this should work for you.

```
<title><?php echo html_entity_decode($title) ?> </title>
```

Comment: I hope that is a spelling mistake? htm_entity_decode? It should be html_entity_decode. Anyhow, then please show your code.

Comment: no sorry i try again with html but it doesnt work i edited my questions